# How to start ansible script in given time

Tags: ansible

I need to run a ansible-playbook everyday at a scheduled time.How can I do that? I refer 'at' module.but it helps to execute playbook only one time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **cron** functionality of Ansible. Following is example for that

```
- name: Ensure a job that runs at 5. Creates an entry like "0 5 * * ls -alh > /dev/null"
  cron:
    name: "check dirs"
    minute: "0"
    hour: "5"
    job: "ls -alh > /dev/null"
```

For more information you can refer https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/cron_module.html

Comment: Was this helpful, or you are looking for some specific options to execute your job at scheduled time